# Flicking through many tabs in a jquery-ui "tabs" control

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

Is there a way to make the jquery-ui "tabs" control display small arrows when there are many tabs open, so that the user can flick through them (like in a Firefox window with many tabs open)? If not, are there any tab controls that implement this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could add a css rule that target open tabs and an image for example:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-selected{
    background-image: url(....);
}
```